# How to write proper Scala with immutable collections and if statement?

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

I want the following function: taking the following parameters:

- `def filters: Map[String, String]`
- `def queryString: Map[String, Seq[String]]` (from request.queryString)
- `def key: String`

.. if `queryString` contains the `key` specified in parameter, I want to add the corresponding value to `filters`.

A working function is:

```
private def getUpdatedFiltersIfQueryStringContains(filters: Map[String, String], queryString: Map[String, Seq[String]], key: String): Map[String, String] = {
  var updatedFilters: Map[String, String] = filters

  if (queryString.contains(key)) {
    updatedFilters = updatedFilters ++ Map(key -> queryString.get(key).get.head)
  }

  updatedFilters
}
```

This looks horrendous, right?

Since `if` statements return stuff in Scala, I was expecting something more along those lines:

```
private def getUpdatedFiltersIfQueryStringContains(filters: Map[String, String], queryString: Map[String, Seq[String]], key: String): Map[String, String] = {
  if (queryString.contains(key)) {
    filters ++ Map(key -> queryString.get(key).get.head)
  }
}
```

But this doesn't compile, the error is:

> type mismatch; found : Unit required: Map[String,String]

Comment: Scala does not a an if-statement - it has an if-expression. As you already said, they return a value - a statement is the name for an instruction that doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function signature states that `Map[String, String]` should be returned, but ... hold on a second and imagine, what if queryString doesn't contain a key? Well, looks like nothing will be returned, and Unit is nothing in Scala (at least one of the nothing kinds).

To fix that problem you need to provide alternative:

```
private def getUpdatedFiltersIfQueryStringContains(filters: Map[String, String], queryString: Map[String, Seq[String]], key: String): Map[String, String] = {
    if (queryString.contains(key)) {
      filters ++ Map(key -> queryString.get(key).get.head)
    } else filters
  }
```

*by the way, function name really scares me*

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted. Samuel's solution is a one liner, but looks also a bit more obscure to a newbie.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the more monadic

`queryString.get(key) map { v => filters ++ Map(key -> v.head) } getOrElse filters`

which does what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more idiomatic implementation that doesn't use `if`:

```
def getUpdatedFiltersIfQueryStringContains(filters: Map[String, String], queryString: Map[String, Seq[String]], key: String): Map[String, String] =
  filters ++ queryString.get(key).map(key -> _.head)
```

Comment: Aren't you lacking a Map here? You can't ++ a pair to a map, can you?

Comment: `Map[K,V].get(key)` returns an `Option[V]`, which is basically just a collection limited to size 0 or 1. You can use `++` on it and `map` across it just like other collections. Scala 2.10 even added fold operations to Option.

Comment: There is an implicit conversion from `Option[A]` to `Iterable[A]`, and `++` allows you to append an `Iterable[(A, B)]` to a `Map[A, B]`.